# Problem with hairon cycles render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I have this problem and i don't know what's really causing it.
[image]
As you can see, the first particle system looks fine, but the don't look so good, they can't barely be seen, and seems bugged

The hair settings of the 3 particle systems are exactly the same (the only thing i changed were the children displays)

Here is the complete hair on normal viewport
[image]

I tried changing the stack order, the hair cycles settings, but nothing can solve it.

Anyone knows what's happening and what should i do?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Am I the only one thinking the problem is not specified enough? In fact I really dunno what is the 1st particle system and why it looks good and what is the 3rd one and why it looks bad. The 1st image looks weird with those particle "points" but other than that I dunno what has to be done...

Comment: Its the same image. Look, the thing goes like this. I was creating some hair for a character, then i went to cycles renderviewport and "¡tada!", te 2nd and 3rd particle systems looks awful, while the first one looks good. I started a new one, and at first it looked good, but then when i finished it, it looks awful (like the other 2 particle systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me/you from the future.
The "problem" with the particle system is that in the Cycles Hair Settings the "Shape" Bar was in 1, so it looks like that because of that, turn it back to 0 to make the hair look good again ^^

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, it solved my problem :)

Comment: You may want to accept the answer from yourself in the future so that if you find yourself in the distant future, you know the question is closed ;)

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for reminding me that. Question is officially closed ;)

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for reminding me that. Question is officially closed ;)